# Set value for private final static inlined variable using Mockito

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, mockito, spring-test

I'm trying to test a method which calls another method which makes use of a private final static variable initialized inline. I'm then trying to change the value for the variable when the tests run. I've been trying things such as spring reflection or adding a setter for that specific field but maybe I should use something as powermock, which I never used before. I'm on my own trying to implement this with no one to ask so if I could have some guidance on what is the best way to proceed, please.

**UPDATE**

Based on some feedback I got here, mocking the private final variable may not be what I should do for my my tests. I've opened a different issue here [Mock return value for cookie.getValue() using Mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70462251/mock-return-value-for-cookie-getvalue-using-mockito)

```
@Service
public class CookieSessionUtils {

private static final String VIADUCT_LOCAL_AMP = "viaductLocalAmp"; // Value to be changed when the test runs to test the "if Y" scenario.


public boolean verifyState(HttpServletRequest request, String state) {

    String viaductLocalAmp = getCookieByName(request, VIADUCT_LOCAL_AMP); 

    if (viaductLocalAmp.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

public String getCookieByName(HttpServletRequest request, String cookieName) {
    try {
        Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
        if (cookies != null) {
            for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
                if (cookie.getName().equals(cookieName)) {
                    return cookie.getValue();
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ExceptionLogger.logDetailedError("CookieSessionUtils.getCookieByName", e);
        log.error("Error on Cookie " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return "";
}
```

These are a few of the things I've tried:

```
@Autowired
private CookieSessionUtils cookieSessionUtils;

@Mock
private HttpServletRequest request;

@Test
public void testVerifyState() {

    Cookie mockCookie = Mockito.mock(Cookie.class);
    Mockito.when(mockCookie.getName()).thenReturn("YviaductLocalAmp");

    Mockito.when(request.getCookies()).thenReturn(new Cookie[]{mockCookie});

//  cookieSessionUtils.setViaductLocalAmp("YviaductLocalAmp");

//  setField(cookieSessionUtils, "VIADUCT_LOCAL_AMP", VIADUCT_LOCAL_AMP);

//  Mockito.when(cookieSessionUtils.getCookieByName(request, "YviaductLocalAmp")).thenReturn("Y");

    assertTrue(cookieSessionUtils.verifyState(httpServletRequest, "viaductLocalAmp"));

}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to violate the *information hiding / encapsulation* principle because you are trying to "test code".

But UnitTests do not "test code".
Unit Tests verify *public observable* **behavior**, that is: *return values* and *communication with dependencies*.

The actual content of that constant is an *implementation detail* the Test should not care about.

So what you really should test is, that `verifyState()` returns `true` if the *request* contains a cookie with Name "viaductLocalAmp" and value "Y".

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How would I test for the scenario where the return is false though? Would I not need to set the field to a different value to be able to exercise the condition?

Comment: Maybe I'm mixing up between setting the cookie name and its actual value.

Comment: Maybe this is the part I'm getting wrong as I'm mocking the call to getCookieByName but cookie.getValue is always returning as null. ```if (cookie.getName().equals(cookieName)) {
                        return cookie.getValue();
                    }```

Comment: ```@Test
    public void testVerifyStateWhenCookieNameStartsWithY() {

        Cookie mockCookie = Mockito.mock(Cookie.class);
        when(mockCookie.getName()).thenReturn("viaductLocalAmp");

        when(request.getCookies()).thenReturn(new Cookie[]{mockCookie});

        when(cookieSessionUtils.getCookieByName(request, "viaductLocalAmp")).thenReturn("N");

        assertTrue(cookieSessionUtils.verifyState(httpServletRequest, "viaductLocalAmp"));
    }```

Comment: Sorry, I know it's very hard to read this.

Comment: I think my problem may be other now that I've given up on mocking the private variable. I've opened this new issue here. stackoverflow.com/questions/70462251/… Thank you.

Comment: @FrancislainyCampos *"Would I not need to set the field to a different value to be able to exercise the condition"* **--** No you need to ste the fields `name` and `value` of an `Cookie` object in the `HttpResponse`.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that. I'm accepting your answer and opening this new question here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70478382/how-to-mock-getcookiebyname-when-two-different-cookie-name-using-mockito

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if even Powermock will be able to help.

The recommended way is to not use inline constants which need to be changed while testing.

- If you want to change this, you need to introduce an interface in between which supplies constants. Use one implementation of it for the actual source and one for tests. Switch the implementation while testing.

If you do not want to change this, you could try the below approach with reflection

- Make the field accessible.
- Remove the final modifier
- edit the field value

I got this suggestion from [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/g/powermock/c/kU1cTlco564)

```java
private static void setFinalStatic(Field field, Object newValue) throws Exception {
   Field field = ClassWhereToMockStaticFinalVar.class.getDeclaredField("FieldName");   
   field.setAccessible(true);
 
   // remove final modifier from field
   Field modifiersField = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
   modifiersField.setAccessible(true);
   modifiersField.setInt(field, field.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);
   field.set(null, newValue);
}
```