# How to mock getCookieByName when two different cookie names using Mockito

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have this method which I want to test using mockito

```
public boolean verifyState(HttpServletRequest request) {

    String stateToken = getCookieByName(request, STATE_TOKEN);
    String authToken = getCookieByName(request, AUTHN);

    boolean isValidState = !stateToken.isEmpty() && !authToken.isEmpty();

    if (isValidState) {
        return true;
    }

    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

It does two calls to getCookieName(), which has this implementation.

```
public String getCookieByName(HttpServletRequest request, String cookieName) {
    try {
        Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
        if (cookies != null) {
            for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
                if (cookie.getName().equals(cookieName)) {
                    return cookie.getValue();
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ExceptionLogger.logDetailedError("CookieSessionUtils.getCookieByName", e);
        log.error("Error on Cookie " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return "";
}
```

I then have this for my tests:

```
@WebMvcTest(value = CookieSessionUtils.class, includeFilters =      
{@ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, classes = {ApiOriginFilter.class})}) 
class CookieSessionUtilsTest {

@Autowired
private CookieSessionUtils cookieSessionUtils;

@Mock
private HttpServletRequest request;

@BeforeEach
public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

@Test
public void testVerifyState() {

    Cookie mockCookie1 = Mockito.mock(Cookie.class);
    Cookie mockCookie2 = Mockito.mock(Cookie.class);
    when(mockCookie1.getName()).thenReturn("stateToken");
    when(mockCookie1.getValue()).thenReturn("stateToken");

    when(mockCookie2.getName()).thenReturn("authn");
    when(mockCookie2.getValue()).thenReturn("authn");

    when(request.getCookies()).thenReturn(new Cookie[]{mockCookie1, mockCookie2});
    
    when(cookieSessionUtils.getCookieByName(request, "stateToken")).thenReturn("stateToken");
    when(cookieSessionUtils.getCookieByName(request, "authn")).thenReturn("authn");
    
    assertTrue(cookieSessionUtils.verifyState(request));
}
```

However, it's always failing returning false falling into the `return ""` for the `getCookieByName()` method which seems to be triggered multiple times and having the value for getName() and getValue() overwritten by the other cookie, so it fails on `(cookie.getName().equals(cookieName))`. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, it's being called here  String stateToken = getCookieByName(request, STATE_TOKEN); under the verifyState() method.

Comment: Sure, doing that now.

Comment: Hm... do you have a [MRE], e.g. in form of a git-repository you can share? From the looks of it, it seems that `cookieSessionUtils` is a partial mock and the unit under test, is this correct? I am confused that the actual implementation of `getCookieByName(...)` is called since we mock the call. What we could try is replace `when(cookieSessionUtils.getCookieByName(request, "stateToken")).thenReturn("stateToken");` with `when(cookieSessionUtils.getCookieByName(any(HttpServletRequest.class), eq("stateToken"))).thenReturn("stateToken");`

Comment: Sorry, it's my company's code so I don't have the repo public available to share. I've edited the post showing the classes I'm using. I think the real getCookieByName() method is called because we're autowiring its class? Both this method and the one to be tested are inside the same class.

Comment: We  mock it nevertheless. IIRC, mockito should complain about not being able to mock methods of non-mock classes. Can you condense the code down to a reproducer that you can share? Without it, debugging is near impossible. Also, at least for this test, the autowiring seems superfluous. I do not see why we should autowire  the unit under test instead of just creating it through a `new ...` call (it does not seem that we use any other service/dependency).

Comment: @FrancislainyCampos are you using SpringRunner. @RunWith(SpringRunner.class) ?

Comment: Hi, no. ```@ActiveProfiles(resolver = MyActiveProfileResolver.class)
@WebMvcTest(value = CookieSessionUtils.class, includeFilters = {
        @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, classes = {ApiOriginFilter.class, ValidationFilter.class})})
class CookieSessionUtilsTest {```

Comment: @Turing85 I've been looking at your request for a mvc that I can share, but this project is a bit big so not very easy to make it smaller enough.

Comment: @FrancislainyCampos try changing `@Mock` with `@MockBean` and remove @BeforeEach setup method.

Comment: Just tried that now but got the same error I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to be so complicated. For mocking the servlet stuff, you can simply use the mock implementation provided by spring-test. It is more convenient to use than Mockito.

You can simply write your test case as :

```java
@Test
public void testVerifyState() {

    MockHttpServletRequest request = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/dummy")
            .cookie(new MockCookie("stateToken", "stateToken"))
            .cookie(new MockCookie("authn", "authn"))
            .buildRequest(new MockServletContext());

    assertTrue(cookieSessionUtils.verifyState(request));        
}
```

Also , if the `CookieSessionUtils` that you are testing is just an utility class which does not have other spring bean dependencies, you can further simplify your test to just a plain JUnit test rather than a `@WebMvcTest`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [@kenChan's answer,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70479267/6654475) both of the below methods work. The issue was actually something very subtle and trivial. The value for the cookie was "authn" but its name is "Authn", so there wasn't a match between them due to capitalization.

```
private static final String STATE_TOKEN = "stateToken";
private static final String AUTHN = "Authn";


@Test
public void testVerifyState1() {

    Cookie mockCookie1 = Mockito.mock(Cookie.class);
    Cookie mockCookie2 = Mockito.mock(Cookie.class);
    when(mockCookie1.getName()).thenReturn("stateToken");
    when(mockCookie1.getValue()).thenReturn("stateToken");

    when(mockCookie2.getName()).thenReturn("authn");
    when(mockCookie2.getValue()).thenReturn("Authn");

    when(request.getCookies()).thenReturn(new Cookie[]{mockCookie1, mockCookie2});

    when(cookieSessionUtils.getCookieByName(request, "stateToken")).thenReturn("stateToken");
    when(cookieSessionUtils.getCookieByName(request, "Authn")).thenReturn("Authn");

    assertTrue(cookieSessionUtils.verifyState(request, ""));
}


@Test
public void testVerifyState() {

    MockHttpServletRequest request = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/dummy")
            .cookie(new MockCookie("stateToken", "stateToken"))
            .cookie(new MockCookie("Authn", "authn"))
            .buildRequest(new MockServletContext());

    assertTrue(cookieSessionUtils.verifyState(request, ""));
}
```